# LIKE подобный запрос, с использованием xpath в postrgesql

Tags: база-данных, xml, postgresql, xpath

Добрый вечер!
У меня имеется простая база данных, в которой хранится xml - данные, в данном случае автор книги и её текст.
Вопрос как осуществить поиск типа LIKE, чтобы не писать полное содержание книги или полностью автора.
На данный момент я делаю такой запрос:

```
SELECT * from storage where (xpath('//book/author/text()', documentcontent))[1]::text = 'Толстой Лев Николаевич'::text;
```

Comment: В xpath есть функция `contains`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем получилось у меня найти ответ, вышло их целых два.

Первый вариант вытаскивает только **ОДНО** значение вместе с тегами из XML документа хранящегося в таблице:

```
SELECT unnest(xpath('//ЗДЕСЬ УКАЗАТЬ УЗЕЛ/*[contains(text(),"ТУТ НАПИСАТЬ ИЛИ УКАЗАТЬ ЧАСТЬ ТЕКСТА, КОТОРЫЙ ХРАНИТСЯ В XML")]', ТУТ УКАЗАТЬ ИМЯ ПОЛЯ::xml))::text AS XMLDATA FROM ТУТ УКАЗАТЬ ИМЯ ТАБЛИЦЫ;
```

Второй вариант вытаскивает **ВСЕ** значение вместе с тегами из XML документа хранящиеся в таблице:

```
SELECT  * from ТУТ УКАЗАТЬ ИМЯ ТАБЛИЦЫ where (xpath('//ЗДЕСЬ УКАЗАТЬ УЗЕЛ', ТУТ УКАЗАТЬ ИМЯ ПОЛЯ))[1]::text ILIKE '%ТУТ УКАЗАТЬ ФРАЗУ ЧАСТЬЮ ИЛИ ЦЕЛИКОМ'::text;
```

Надеюсь вам поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Есть contains, которая аналогична LIKE.

Используется вот так:

```
.//span[contains(text(),"текст внутри элемента")]
```